# fill custom shapes in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

Can anyone guide me how to fill these closed shapes. I am done with the drawing part. Now I want to add the functionality that if the user draws a closed shape it gets filled automatically. Secondly if an open shape is closed by the user later on it also gets filled. I don't know what to look for in order to implement this so need guidance. Sample image is posted below. Here I want to fill the closed shapes in green. The code used for drawing is

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(mBitmap!=null){
    canvas.drawBitmap(drawableBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    System.out.println("NOTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");

    canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);

    canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);}
    else
        System.out.println("I am nullllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll");
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
         mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
    }
    private void touch_up() {


        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    if(mCanvas!=null)
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);

    else

        System.out.println("I AM MCANVASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    float x = arg1.getX();
    float y = arg1.getY();

    switch (arg1.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: For clarity, in this picture you would want the eyes to be auto-filled completely yellow?

Comment: How exactly are they drawing the shapes? Code would be useful.

Comment: @TheJavaCoder16 The eyes should be filled with green..

Comment: @TheJavaCoder16 I think what they want is any closed shape to be filled in (eg. the eyes), while any line/non-closed shape would stay "open" (eg. the mouth)

Comment: @user3485978 So currently, the app just draws lines on the image, correct?

Comment: @kkirigaya yes currently my code just do free hand drawing.

Comment: You could store drawn paths in a `List`, and compare path coordinates with them when done drawing a new segment.

Comment: @MeetTitan how can I fill the shape after completing it?

Comment: Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL).

Comment: Sorry, my monitor doesn't have great color accuracy. @user3485978

Comment: @MeetTitan this fills the path while drawing the shape. I want to fill the shape after completing it.

Comment: Only use that paint if the shape is completed.

Comment: @MeetTitan yes it worked!!

Comment: @user3485978, glad to hear it! You got it with just a hint, as well. Good job!